# Wordpress advanced Taxonomy query with custom field ( date type ) ordering

Tags: wordpress

This is the Advanced taxonomy query array I ended up building.

But it returns 0 posts.

If I remove the item ( `[orderby] => meta_value_num`), then I get posts, but posts that do not factor in the custom field in the query at all.

What am I doing wrong?

```
 [posts_per_page] => 6
    [order] => DESC
    [ignore_sticky_posts] => 1
    [orderby] => meta_value_num
    [meta_key] => wpcf-sort-order
    [tax_query] => Array
        (
            [relation] => AND
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [taxonomy] => category
                    [field] => slug
                    [terms] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => featured
                        )

                    [operator] => AND
                    [include_children] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [taxonomy] => category
                    [field] => slug
                    [terms] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => politics
                            [1] => science
                        )

                    [operator] => IN
                    [include_children] => 1
                )

        )

    [paged] => 1
)
```

Custom field stores the dates in this format:1475773260